# How can I input a string in a scanner and convert it into character and that character becomes my stack?

Tags: java, arrays, stack, character

I am new to java and I am stuck with my code because I have no idea how my character becomes my stack

```
Stack<Character> charStack = new Stack<Character>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a word: ");
        String str = scan.nextLine();
        char[] char1 = new char [str.length()];

        for (int b = 0; b<char1.length; b++){
            charStack.push(b);
            System.out.println(charStack);
            charStack.pop(); 
}
```

> error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Character
> charStack.push(b);

```
   and the output should be:
      ['W','O','R','D']
      ['W','O','R']  
      ['W','O'] 
      ['W']
```

Comment: There are two issues with your code 

Instead of this `char[] char1 = new char [str.length()];` convert your input string to character array like this `str.toCharArray()`

Then instead of pushing the `index` integer to the character stack, push the character `charStack.push(charArray[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code

Instead of this `char[] char1 = new char [str.length()];` convert your input string to character array like this `str.toCharArray()`

Then instead of pushing the `index` integer to the character stack, push the character `charStack.push(charArray[i]);`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Stack<Character> charStack = new Stack<Character>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input a word: ");
    String str = scan.nextLine();
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        charStack.push(charArray[i]);
    }
    while (!charStack.empty()) {
        System.out.println(charStack);
        charStack.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: but how do I make the output like
['T','H','A','N','K','S']
['T','H','A','N','K']
['T','H','A','N']
['T','H','A']

Comment: @ouieraphael remove the pop after this line`System.out.println(charStack);` 
then add this code
  `while (!charStack.empty()) {
            System.out.println(charStack);
            charStack.pop();
        }`
you would have output like ['T','H','A','N','K','S'] ['T','H','A','N','K'] ['T','H','A','N'] ['T','H','A'] ['T','H'] ['T']

Comment: @ouieraphael updated answer, please check